# How to select other rows in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb

Sorry for the bad title. I don't know how to summarize it better.
I have a table with unix timestamps and other values, like the following.

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1620916380 | 110 |
| 1620916440 | 100 |
| 1620916500 | 120 |
| 1620916560 | 120 |
| 1620916660 | 90 |

The entries are always one minute apart.
I want to group entries into 5-minute blocks with the value averaged. Currently I use this:

```
SELECT time, avg(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY CEIL(time/ 300)
ORDER BY time ASC;
```

The result:

| time | avg(value) |
| --- | --- |
| 1620916380 | 108 |

So, for time the first occurrence is shown. I want the last to be shown:

| time | avg(value) |
| --- | --- |
| 1620916660 | 108 |

How can I do that? I use MariaDB.

Comment: Your example data does not produce the result that you have in your post, since `CEIL(time/ 300)` is not the same for the five rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you just want MAX(time)?

```
SELECT MAX(time) AS time
     , avg(value)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY CEIL(time/ 300)
 ORDER BY time ASC
;
```

For completeness, we should mention that the original query is not valid (per standard SQL), even though MariaDB can be configured to allow it.

The reason is `time` in the `select list` is not functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY`  terms `CEIL(time/300)`.

Selecting `MAX(time) AS time` in the solution corrects the above functional dependence issue, and also corrects a similar issue when trying to use `ORDER BY time`, which was also a problem in the original query.

Comment: Such an easy solution. I don't know why I didn't think of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try order time by descending order.. As below
 `SELECT time, avg(value) FROM table GROUP BY CEIL(time/ 300) ORDER BY time DESC`

Comment: That does not change the time value that is selected in each row.

Comment: Then Just try SELECT MAX(time) 
     , avg(value)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY CEIL(time/ 300)
 ORDER BY time ASC
;

Comment: That's not really valid either :)   Though MariaDB is often configured to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(time), avg(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY CEIL(time/ 300)
ORDER BY time ASC;
```